# Multiple Column Dropdown in Details View control

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have created a dropdown list in a DetailsView control

I want to make that dropdown have multiple columns. Is that possible? If So how?
I've done a lot of searching and cant seem to find the solution.

Below is the code for my dropdown template:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="fDivisionID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList
                             ID="DivisionDropDownList" 
                             runat="server" 
                             DataSourceID="DivisionSqlDataSource"
                             DataTextField="DivisionName" 
                             DataValueField="DivisionID" 
                             Text='<%# Bind("fDivisionID") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DivisionName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

How do I add another column to that.. such as "Location"..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are I think three ways actually.

1. Add two columns in your Select statement when fetching from database like below. or from **[here](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2009/03/how-to-create-multi-column-dropdownlist.html)**

   Select Column1 + ' ' + Column2 From Yourtable
2. You can use third party controls.
3. Jquery Also supports this feature **[Here](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm)**

Comment: This is to do it using other controls... Can it be done within the Dataview control?

Comment: Thanks..I've gone another way and created a new field and combined what I need in there and used that.  What you're suggesting cannot be done within the detailsview control

Comment: You can do it in dropdownlist to show multiple columns by appending text or by other options as mentioned above.